# cleveref package problem in appendix

Tags: pdftex, cross-referencing, appendices

my friends,
I have several problems with cross-referencing by cleveref package. when I call this package in my appendix section, the equations are shown as "Appendix A.2 and Appendix A.2" instead of "Equations (A.5) and (A.8)". The attached images show what I typed and what I produced. How can I solve this problem?

[image: The typed command]

[image: The result]

This is a sample which generates the same problem

```
 ‎\documentclass[review]{article}‎  
 \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,raiselinks=true,colorlinks,linktoc=all]{hyperref}‎
 \usepackage{amsmath}‎
 \usepackage{nicefrac}‎
 \usepackage{cleveref}
 ‎\begin{document}‎

 \section{Bibliography styles}‎
 There are various bibliography styles available‎. ‎You can select the style of your choice in the preamble of this document‎. ‎These styles are Elsevier styles based on standard styles like Harvard and Vancouver‎. ‎Please use Bib\TeX\ to generate your bibliography and include DOIs whenever available‎.

 \begin{appendix}‎‎‎
 \setcounter{table}{1} \renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}
 \section{Turbulence models} \label{appendix:1}‎
 In this section‎, ‎the governing and model equations for three turbulence models‎: ‎the zonal $k-\varepsilon$‎, ‎the linear low-Reynolds $k-\varepsilon$‎, ‎and the nonlinear low-Reynolds $k-\varepsilon$ are presented‎. ‎Also‎, ‎the relations of Yap length-scale correction term and its new differential form are given‎.
 \subsection{Mean flow equations}‎
 For the incompressible flow in steady state condition‎, ‎the conservation laws of mass‎, ‎momentum‎, ‎and energy can be written as‎

 Continuity‎:

 \begin{eqnarray}‎
 \frac{ \partial U_{i}}{ \partial x_{i}}=0‎,
 \label{eq:A-1}‎
 \end{eqnarray}‎

 Momentum‎:
 \begin{eqnarray}‎
 \frac{ \partial  \left( U_{j}U_{i} \right) }{ \partial x_{j}}=-\frac{1}{ \rho }\frac{ \partial P}{ \partial x_{i}}+\frac{ \partial }{ \partial x_{j}} \left(  \nu \frac{ \partial U_{i}}{ \partial x_{j}}-\overline{u_{i}u_{j}}\right)‎,
 ‎\label{eq:A-2}‎
 \end{eqnarray}‎

 Energy‎:
 \begin{eqnarray}‎
 \frac{ \partial  \left( U_{j} \Theta  \right) }{ \partial x_{j}}=\frac{ \partial }{ \partial x_{j}} \left( \frac{ \nu }{Pr}\frac{ \partial  \Theta }{ \partial x_{j}}-\overline{u_{j} \theta } \right)‎.
 \label{eq:A-3}‎
 \end{eqnarray}‎

 where the first order tensor $‎- ‎\rho c_{p} \overline{u_{j} \theta}$ and the second order tensor $-\rho \overline{u_{i}u_{j}}$ are the unknown turbulent heat flux and Reynolds stresses‎, ‎respectively‎. ‎These variables should be determined by turbulence modeling‎.

 \subsection{Zonal $k-\varepsilon$ model}‎
 In this turbulence model‎, ‎the Reynolds stresses and heat flux are obtained by eddy-viscosity and eddy-diffusivity approximations‎, ‎as follows‎

 \begin{eqnarray}‎
 \overline{u_{i}u_{j}}={2}\big/{3} \delta _{ij}k-\nu _{t} \left( \frac{ \partial U_{i}}{ \partial x_{j}}+\frac{ \partial U_{j}}{ \partial x_{i}} \right)‎,
 \label{eq:A-4}‎
 \end{eqnarray}‎

 \begin{eqnarray}‎
 \overline{u_{i} \theta }=-\frac{ \nu _{t}}{ \sigma _{ \theta }}\frac{ \partial  \Theta }{ \partial x_{i}}‎,
 \label{eq:A-5}‎
 \end{eqnarray}‎
 where the turbulent viscosity‎, ‎$\nu_t$‎, ‎is obtained from‎ 
 \begin{eqnarray}‎
 \nu _{t}=c_{ \mu }\frac{k^{2}}{ \varepsilon }‎.
 \label{eq:A-6}‎
 \end{eqnarray}‎

 To obtain $\nu _{t}$‎, ‎the computational domain is divided into two regions‎: ‎the fully turbulent region and the low-Reynolds number near wall region‎. ‎Inside the fully turbulent region‎, ‎the standard high Reynolds $k-\varepsilon$ model is employed‎. ‎In this turbulence model‎, ‎the transport equations for turbulent kinetic energy and its dissipation rate are written as‎

 \begin{eqnarray}‎
 \frac{ \partial }{ \partial x_{j}} \left( U_{j}k \right) =\frac{ \partial }{ \partial x_{j}} \left[  \left( \frac{ \nu _{t}}{ \sigma _{k}} \right) \frac{ \partial k}{ \partial x_{j}} \right]‎ ‎+P_{k}-‎ ‎\varepsilon‎,
 \label{eq:A7}
 \end{eqnarray}‎

 \begin{eqnarray}‎
 \frac{ \partial }{ \partial x_{j}} \left( U_{j} \varepsilon  \right) =\frac{ \partial }{ \partial x_{j}} \left[  \left( \frac{ \nu _{t}}{ \sigma _{ \varepsilon }} \right) \frac{ \partial  \varepsilon }{ \partial x_{j}} \right]‎ +‎c_{ \varepsilon 1}\frac{ \varepsilon }{k}P_{k}-c_{ \varepsilon 2}\frac{ \varepsilon ^{2}}{k}‎,
 \label{eq:A-8}‎
 \end{eqnarray}‎
 where the turbulent kinetic energy production term‎, ‎$P_{k}$‎, ‎is given by‎
 \begin{eqnarray}‎
 P_{k}=-\overline{u_{i}u_{j}}\frac{ \partial U_{i}}{ \partial x_{j}}‎.
 \label{eq:A-9}‎
 \end{eqnarray}‎
 The coefficients in \Cref{eq:A-5,eq:A-8} ‎‎Equations~\eqref{eq:A-5} and~\eqref{eq:A-8}‎ are given in \autoref{tab:A-2}‎. ‎For modeling the near wall region‎, ‎a low-Reynolds number one-equation model is used‎. ‎In this model‎, ‎the required transport equation for turbulent kinetic energy is the same as to \autoref{eq:A7}‎.
 On the other hand‎, ‎the dissipation rate‎, ‎$\varepsilon$‎, ‎is obtained from the following algebraic relation‎

 \label{appendix}‎
 \end{appendix}‎

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Using `cleveref` for the appendix works normally just fine, please add a MWE that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I cannot add a MWE since I have so large code, which I don't know how to minimize it. Have you any idea?

Comment: Please have a look at https://texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl - this explains how to create a MWE

Comment: It works in the normal text so good. But the problem is in the appendix section.

Comment: `\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

test \cref{key}

\appendix

\chapter{title}

\section{title}

\begin{equation}
content...
\label{key}
\end{equation}

\end{document}` works just fine, so we really need to see a MWE - we cannot read minds what might or might not go on in this mysterious document

Comment: BTW using numeric keys for your equations bereaves you of all the advantages of tex's label/ref mechanism

Comment: did you see the edit?

Comment: If you're using `eqnarray`, don't: it's known to be incompatible with both `hyperref` and `cleveref`. Use `equation` for single equations and `align` for multiple equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in using `eqnarray`, which is not supported by neither `hyperref` nor `cleveref`. Use `equation` for single equations, `align` for multiline displays.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,raiselinks=true,colorlinks,linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Bibliography styles}
There are various bibliography styles available. You can select 
the style of your choice in the preamble of this document. 
These styles are Elsevier styles based on standard styles like 
Harvard and Vancouver. Please use Bib\TeX\ to generate your 
bibliography and include DOIs whenever available.

\appendix
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}

\section{Turbulence models}\label{appendix:1}
In this section, the governing and model equations for 
three turbulence models: the zonal $k-\varepsilon$,
the linear low-Reynolds $k-\varepsilon$, and the nonlinear 
low-Reynolds $k-\varepsilon$ are presented. Also, the 
relations of Yap length-scale correction term and its 
new differential form are given.

\subsection{Mean flow equations}
For the incompressible flow in steady state condition, the 
conservation laws of mass, momentum, and energy can be written as

Continuity:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial U_{i}}{\partial x_{i}}=0,
\label{eq:A-1}
\end{equation}

Momentum:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial(U_{j}U_{i})}{\partial x_{j}}=
-\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial P}{\partial x_{i}}
+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left(
  \nu\frac{\partial U_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}-\overline{u_{i}u_{j}}
\right),
\label{eq:A-2}
\end{equation}

Energy:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial(U_{j}\Theta)}{\partial x_{j}}=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left(
  \frac{\nu}{Pr}\frac{\partial\Theta}{\partial x_{j}}
  -\overline{u_{j}\theta}
\right).
\label{eq:A-3}
\end{equation}
where the first order tensor $-\rho c_{p}\overline{u_{j}\theta}$ 
and the second order tensor $-\rho \overline{u_{i}u_{j}}$ are 
the unknown turbulent heat flux and Reynolds stresses, respectively.
These variables should be determined by turbulence modeling.

\subsection{Zonal $k-\varepsilon$ model}
In this turbulence model, the Reynolds stresses and heat flux are 
obtained by eddy-viscosity and eddy-diffusivity approximations, as follows
\begin{align}
\overline{u_{i}u_{j}}&=\frac{2}{3}\delta _{ij}k-\nu _{t}\left(
  \frac{\partial U_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}
  +\frac{\partial U_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}\right),
\label{eq:A-4}
\\
\overline{u_{i}\theta}&=
  -\frac{\nu _{t}}{\sigma_{\theta}}\frac{\partial\Theta}{\partial x_{i}},
\label{eq:A-5}
\end{align}
where the turbulent viscosity, $\nu_t$, is obtained from 
\begin{equation}
\nu _{t}=c_{\mu}\frac{k^{2}}{\varepsilon}.
\label{eq:A-6}
\end{equation}

To obtain $\nu_{t}$, the computational domain is divided into 
two regions: the fully turbulent region and the low-Reynolds 
number near wall region. Inside the fully turbulent region,
the standard high Reynolds $k-\varepsilon$ model is employed.
In this turbulence model, the transport equations for turbulent 
kinetic energy and its dissipation rate are written as
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}(U_{j}k)&=
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left[
    \left(\frac{\nu_{t}}{\sigma_{k}}\right)
    \frac{\partial k}{\partial x_{j}}
  \right]+P_{k}-\varepsilon,
\label{eq:A7}
\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}(U_{j}\varepsilon)&=
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left[
    \left(\frac{\nu_{t}}{\sigma_{\varepsilon}}\right)
    \frac{\partial\varepsilon}{\partial x_{j}}
  \right]
  +c_{\varepsilon 1}\frac{\varepsilon}{k}P_{k}
  -c_{\varepsilon 2}\frac{\varepsilon^{2}}{k},
\label{eq:A-8}
\end{align}
 where the turbulent kinetic energy production term, $P_{k}$, is given by
\begin{equation}
P_{k}=-\overline{u_{i}u_{j}}\frac{\partial U_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}.
\label{eq:A-9}
\end{equation}
The coefficients in \Cref{eq:A-5,eq:A-8} are given in \Cref{tab:A-2}. 
For modeling the near wall region, a low-Reynolds number one-equation 
model is used. In this model, the required transport equation for turbulent 
kinetic energy is the same as to \Cref{eq:A7}. On the other hand, the 
dissipation rate, $\varepsilon$, is obtained from the following algebraic relation

\end{document}
```

There is still a `??` for the missing table reference.

A few points to note:

1. Beware of U+200E characters in your input
2. *Never ever* use `eqnarray`
3. `\appendix` is a command
4. The `table` counter should be reset to 0, not 1

[image]